# The linearization of the logical constraints

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, solver, logical-constraints, algorithms

I know the logical constraints can be linearized by either the logical representation of whose relation, (for pure binary variables e.g. CNF/DNF) or for general form by using Big-M formulation. As I have recently seen there are other methods like ***convex-hull or cutting-plan transformation*** to do that in which one can use those and often perform faster than Big-M formulation. I would like to know, is there any simple example of how these methods work and do they implement in the modern solvers?

Comment: Are looking for something like this: https://www.gurobi.com/resources/mixed-integer-programming-mip-a-primer-on-the-basics/ (see Cutting planes section). Besides here are more https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/uploads/2022-10-Paris_Advanced_Algorithms.pdf?x47079

Comment: @Sutanu, thanks for the comments. But, what I am looking for is based on this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1570794603804443?via%3Dihub) in which the authors proposed two different methods to solve a GDP.